# knitr:::pandoc skipping images from md -> docx

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I'm using knitr to produce markdown and convert to docx using pander. I can run [this example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/088-pandoc-embedded.md) file using knitr's `pandoc("/full/path/to//088-pandoc-embedded.md", format = "docx")` and everything works fine.

In that markdown document, the image references are to an external file (`http://animation.r-forge.r-project.org/knitr-ex/figure/088-pandoc-embedded-lm-vis.png`). If I save this file locally and use `088-pandoc-embedded-lm-vis.png` in the reference, the image is skipped.

The same occurs when images are deposited in the standard `Figure` directory when knitting a `Rmd` file.

Is there any work-around for this?

Thanks,

Max

```
 > sessionInfo()
 R Under development (unstable) (2013-12-28 r64574)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

 locale:
 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets       methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] knitr_1.5

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.10   stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.0
```

and pandoc 1.12.3.

Comment: do not use that `.md` file on Github; run `knit('088-pandoc-embedded.Rmd')` by yourself to get `088-pandoc-embedded.md`, then run `pandoc()`